# Magento 1.7.0.2 create attribute programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, category-attribute

I am creating a small magento extension to add a link to category banner image

I have this code to create an attribute but seems not to be working

app/code/community/Klevis/CategoryBannerLink/sql/Klevis_CategoryBannerLink_setup/install-0.0.1.php

```
 <?php 
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'category_banner_link', array(
'group'             => 'General',
'type'              => 'varchar',
'backend'           => '', 
'frontend_input'    => '',
'frontend'          => '',
'label'             => 'Banner Link',
'input'             => 'text',
'class'             => '',
'source'            => '', 
'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL, 
'visible'           => true, 
'frontend_class'    => '',
'required'          => false,
'user_defined'      => true,
'default'           => '',
'unique'            => false,
'note'              => ''
));
$this->endSetup();
Config file
```

app/code/community/Klevis/CategoryBannerLink/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Klevis_CategoryBannerLink>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Klevis_CategoryBannerLink>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
        <Klevis_CategoryBannerLink_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Klevis_CategoryBannerLink</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </Klevis_CategoryBannerLink_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
</config>
```

Modules Xml file app/etc/modules/Klevis_CategoryBannerLink.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Klevis_CategoryBannerLink>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Klevis_CategoryBannerLink>
</modules>
</config>
```

I don't see why this it not working. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please verify if any answer among these matches your requirements, or else share what else is needed. It helps others having same issues to navigate easily to the answer that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Please go through these link I hope you find a good solution:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/programmatically_adding_attributes_and_attribute_sets

http://www.pixlpitch.com/programmatically-add-attribute-to-an-attribute-set-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your code examples that you have set-up your code pool via the file `app/etc/modules/Klevis_CategoryBannerLink.xml` as local:

```
<codePool>local</codePool>
```

But your code is actually in the community pool by looking at your file names.

```
app/code/community/Klevis/CategoryBannerLink/etc/config.xml
```

With this in mind either move the files to the local pool or simply update the `codePool` to community.

Answer (score 0):

Check the core_resource table to See if the Version number of your Extension is listed. In order to Run your installer script is has to be lower then in the module xml file